# Code Splitting loads all bundles into html

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, code-splitting

How does code splitting know which chunks go with which entry? For example I have two pages, on page uses AgGrid and another page uses ReactTable for example.

I code split and get vendor.1.bundle.js (contains AgGrid) and vendor.2.bundle.js( contains ReactTable)

I set up my entry:

```
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.jsx',
      review: './src/review.jsx'
    },

    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
      },

     // plugins
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: true,
        excludeChunks: ['review'],
        template: 'src/pages/index.html'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'review.html',
        inject: true,
        excludeChunks: ['index'],
        template: 'src/pages/review.html'
      }),
```

What I end up with is two html files with both vendor files instead of one vendor file containing the deps needed per page.

Shouldn't index which uses AgGrid only load vendor.1.bundle.js and review.html load only vendor.1.html? I thought that was the point of code splitting. Otherwise why not just make 1 huge shared bundle between both pages, I think that would defeat the point. Not sure what I'm doing wrong in this setup however.

Comment: Got a similar issue. Anyone found a solution?